# SQL Count project items where project status history is within date range

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 4 tables:

```
projects: id, title, current_status_id
statuses: id, label
status_history: project_id, status_id, created_at
messages: id, project_id, body, created_at
```

A status_history row is inserted when, in the application, the project changes status (say, from "lead" to "active" to "complete"). Note the created_at column is a timestamp that records the date of the change. Between status changes, activity is happening in the project and messages are created. For example, the project is initialized with a "lead" status, some messages are created while the project is in this "lead" state, the project is changed to "active" status, some messages are created while the project is in this state, and so on.

I want to create query that shows: date, # of messages created in "lead" projects, # messages created in "active" projects, and # messages in projects with other statuses. Can this be done all in one query? I am using PostgreSQL.

---

Here is some pseudo-code that hopefully illuminates what I'm looking for.

```
* Start at the earliest date
* Find all projects whose status was 'lead' on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* Find all projects whose status was 'active' on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* Find all projects whose status was anything else on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* ... some projects change status, some stay the same, business happens ...
* Go to next date
* Find all projects whose status was 'lead' on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* Find all projects whose status was 'active' on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* Find all projects whose status was anything else on that date
* Count the number of created messages from these projects with that date
* ... some projects change status, some stay the same, business happens ...
* keep doing this until the present
```

While the project does have a current_status_id column, it is the present status and not necessarily the status of the project last month. The status of the project does not change every day - a status_history row is not created every day for every project.

Comment: You can create such a query if there is a linking column to join the tables that contain Date, Messages, Projects and Status

Comment: For the given date you want the count of projects NEWLY created w/ those categories, right? Not ones that may have changed to one of those statuses on the given date?

Comment: Hey Brian, for a given date I want to count the number of messages in any project with a certain status. The status of the projects change over time, so some messages may have been created while the project was a lead, some may bave occurred while the project is active, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a query like this...This is MSSQL but I assume very similar to Postgresql or you can simply find the correct syntaxes online.

```
SELECT count(*) AS 'count', messages.created_at, statuses.label
FROM messages
JOIN projects ON projects.id = messages.project_id
JOIN status_history ON projects.id = status_history.project_id
JOIN statuses ON statuses.id ON status_history.status_id
GROUP BY created_at, statues.label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

Replace "lead" and "active" with the status IDs for those 2 statuses.

Note that the first field being selected is a conversion of your created_at timestamp to a date value (removing time).

The counts provided show the number of projects newly created with those statuses. They do not include projects who were already around but which changed to those statuses on the given days. This is accomplished via the not exists subquery.

```
select      date(created_at) as dt
            , sum(case when sh.status_id = 'lead' then 1 else 0 end) as num_lead
            , sum(case when sh.status_id = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as num_active
            , sum(case when sh.status_id not in ('lead','active') then 1 else 0 end) as num_else
from        status_history sh
where       not exists
                    (   select  1
                        from    status_history x
                        where   x.project_id = sh.project_id
                            and x.created_at < sh.created_at    )
group by    date(created_at)
order by    1
```

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the tip but I'm actually trying to count the number of newly created messages.

Comment: @JustinM that is what the query does. It filters out those that already existed via the not exists subquery.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
SELECT to_char(tmp.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as date, COUNT(tmp.status = 'lead') as num_lead,  COUNT(tmp.status = 'active') as num_active FROM 
(
    SELECT m.created_at AS date, COUNT(m.id) as messages, s.label as status FROM messages AS m
    INNER JOIN project AS p ON p.id = m.project_id
    INNER JOIN statuses AS s ON s.id = p.current_status_id
    GROUP BY m.created_at, s.id, s.label
) as tmp
GROUP BY tmp.date;
```

Grouping should be 100%-correct (because it's not clear that one id belongs to exactly one textual-representation, label is not primary_key!)

Temporary table contains all relations of "Messages per date and project_status_label" and the outer select-function only changes dimension.